# Auto-Delete topic when it is idle

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a scenario where I need to create a topic per device and all the events for that event will be moved to that topic

so in broker config, I selected to enable auto topic creation

`auto.create.topics.enable`

but is suggested in documentation that creating a lot of topics can have a bad impact

so I want to auto-delete the topic if the topic is idle for some time

is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Creating too many kafka topic might cause an issue if:
1. Message retention is high
2. # of topic are beyond allowed limits(depends on which cloud or service you are using).

Otherwise it doesn't matter, though its good to clean up the house often :)
Mostly this conf is enabled by default `delete.topic.enable=true` (depends on your kafka version).
You can have a cron job or some script like [here](https://gist.github.com/hartfordfive/5928e7bca7c6239e4e1036346d326953) to delete topics once in a while.

Comment: better use a device identifier in payload Or key of the event. Don't create too much topics

Comment: Please explain your use-case better. Why cant you use one `device-events` topic and put a device ID in the payloads?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I have the same question as the OP, and my use case is that I am building an MQTT proxy frontend to Kafka, and using Kafka Streams to build a device specific topic as an out-topic from a general device-messages in-topic. The device that is connected over MQTT is subscribed and only wants messages for itself. The topic is built with a unique identifier. When the device goes away or logs off for an extended period of time, that topic is no longer necessary. When you have many devices, we want the ability to auto-clean topics, kind of like RabbitMQ queue auto-delete

Comment: I can't edit my original comment r/n, but in my MQTT use-case, we will just be pushing the device specific messages through the MQTT subscription directly from the generic device-messages topic per an ID in the message payload

Comment: @MattFiocca I've never used MQTT or RabbitMQ. But Kafka simply doesn't have the notion of "repeat, subscribing clients" to know if/when any consumer will come back, or scan for "empty" topics on its own. The brokers are very dumb.

Answer (score 1):

in kafka you don't have auto deletion.
you can implement the unnecessary topics deletion,
available in kafka client functionality.